# Mechanically propelled spaceship?

Tags: physics, travel, movement

Is it possible to have some sort of a spaceship that basically runs on electricity and "butt kicks" itself forward? Or would it stand still because every force has an equal force in the opposite direction?

Comment: The only form of space propulsion we currently know requires the ejection of a reaction mass. This spacecraft "butt kicks" against what?  https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/conmo.html

Comment: @JacobKrall currently it's no longer fashionable to say photons have mass. One can also deflect solar wind, and push against magnetic fields. In those cases there is a reaction mass, but not really "ejection" thereof.

Comment: I imagined it having some sort of a spring at the back and mechanical hand that can kick it then the spring would transfer that energy to the ship.

Comment: @Dangz1 your question is about conservation of momentum, and so will be the answer. It's not related to space exploration, just basic physics. And I suspect *you actually know the answer* already too! :)

Comment: @uhoh Yes, the answer is in the question, and it has to do with regular physics--nothing special about space. On the other hand, if the asker wishes to know if it is possible to somehow "push against the vacuum", he should check out our [posts on the EM drive](http://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=EM+drive) keeping in mind that it seems to defy our current understanding of physics and may not be a valid form of propulsion (it is not yet proven).

Comment: In case the ship "ejects" the "hand" afterwards... A railgun as rocket engine? If the Yugoslavian [EDO-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun#Tests) indeed reached 4500m/s of muzzle velocity, that would make a respectable 450s of Specific Impulse. The others (like the US Army's 3km/s) aren't that respectable - a very sub-average rocket can do 300s in void, and with vastly less necessary dry mass.

Comment: It's worth noting that the conservation of momentum is very deeply ingrained in modern physics -- by Noether's theorem it is equivalent to the laws of physics being translation-invariant, i.e., the same everywhere.

Comment: Reactionless drives violate the laws of physics, but [reactionmassless drives don't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactionless_drive#Quasi-reactionless_methods).  Would you consider a gravity assist (flyby) to be mechanically propelled?

Comment: @gerrit who says a gravity assist is reactionless? you are "ejecting" the whole mass of the planet, at very low speed. There's no rule that the propellant must start attached to the spaceship, but it has to exist, somewhere.

Comment: @PcMan A gravity assist is not reactionless, but it's reactionmassless.  No mass is ejected from the spacecraft.  I think it's a bit of a stretch to consider this as ejecting the whole mass of the planet, but if you want to call it that, go ahead.

Comment: @gerrit the whole planet does get shoved back, its orbit changes (by a minute amount, due to the mass ratio, of course).

Comment: @PcMan It does, but I would not call that a reaction mass, by which I would understand a mass carried on the spacecraft.  It's not a propellant.

Comment: @gerrit then you would need to throw out a whole slew of possible drives. Solar sails, gravity slingshot, magnetic drives, even photon drive (as if we have a power source suitable for that!). *all* of these still work by conservation of momentum, shoving one piece of mass rearwards so the rest of the rocket gets shoved forwards.

Answer (score 12):

It would stand still, because of the equal and opposite force rule (aka conservation of momentum).

On earth's surface it's possible to have a self-propelled butt-kicking machine by having a slow "wind-up" phase alternating with an abrupt "kick". During the wind-up, static friction with a ground surface holds the vehicle in place, but the kick phase can break the frictional threshold. However, the momentum of the system of (ground + vehicle) remains conserved, ultimately using the Earth's vast mass as a "momentum sink".

In space, with no ground to brace against, the butt-kicking machine goes nowhere.

Comment: It's been tried: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dean_drive but those darn laws of physics just get in the way.

Comment: So Queen's documentary on what makes the world go 'round was close, but slightly inaccurate?

Comment: I'm trying to imagine this machine - one mass (the butt) is "standing" and the other mass (the kicker) sticks out to the side - when they come together, the whole thing actually moves *in the direction of the kicker* and not in the direction of the kick? This sounds somehow familiar - is there already something thad does this - a toy, or an animal or something?

Comment: I wasn't thinking of any particular real world implementation. If you slowly hoisted a rigid pendulum "boot" then released it to swing against the "butt" resting on the ground, I think net movement would be in the kicking direction?

Comment: This is the Newtonian explanation, but he **is** wrong at more exotic scales. I think it boils down to: Is gravity weaker that electricity?

Comment: I see - I was using a spring, you're using gravity! Now I wanna build or at least animate both. If I was only even slightly talented, the Physics engine in [Blender](http://blender.stackexchange.com/) could do this smartly.

Comment: @DigitalDesignDj: who is "he" (Russell?) and why is he wrong at more exotic scales? Conservation of momentum is equivalent with invariance under translations in space. (I.e. if the laws of physics are the same everywhere, momentum is everywhere conserved). This is a fundamental mathematical property (Noether's theorem), and "exotic scales" do not come into play. While those scales do affect the laws of physics themselves, it doesn't make them location-dependent.

Comment: I'm always a little puzzled when a question about electric butt-kicking machines gets answers about billion-mile wires or relativistically rotating cylinders, myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you used 1.000.000 cubic meters of steel to create a 1 mm² wire spanning a large distance of 1000 million km you might be able to tug spacecraft along it.

Not very practical though and the wire might be unstable or snap.
IF it worked and you could get something like 70 000 N out of it (~70 kg on Earth) that would be quite good though.

You would always need to have spacecraft going both ways to keep it stable and each craft would have to share the max load with all the others.

Comment: Like a space ski lift?

Comment: Doesn't look anywhere _near_ practical: 70.000 N isn't going to accelerate that billion kilometer of wire at any measurable rate, let alone the space ship attached at the end.

Comment: The cable would orbit the sun. The ship would pull on the cable using say a pair of wheels.
I'm not saying it would work, just my best guess for mechanical propulsion.
Very similar to/same as space tethers I think.
Btw 70000 N is a lot in space when applied over many days.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you count as a 'mechanical' you could consider Project Orion. 
(Technically a nuke uses nuclear energy, not mechanical but it would be 'pushed' by the explosion)

Basically, detonate a nuke and use it to propel you. So a very hot kick in the butt.

http://99percentinvisible.org/article/retro-rockets-nuclear-explosion-powered-spaceships-atomic-age/

Comment: It doesn't use electricity for propulsion, and it kicks out a very hot, very radioactive, very fast-moving plume of exhaust behind it in pulses. Essentially, it's just an unusual type of rocket, rather than the unique mode the OP describes.

Comment: What are you referring to with the "It doesn't use electricity for propulsion"? And that is a fair assessment of this answer.

Comment: The fact that, at most, it uses electricity for a very minor thing (positioning the nuclear charges), not the primary motive force. The propulsion proper is entirely nuclear-thermal.